# Error "You must specify a region" when running any aws CLI command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to use aws container service as per the documentation in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_GetStarted.html

The below error is thrown when running the command:

```
aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster default

You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".
```

The documentation does not mention anything about specifying a default region. How do we do it in a console?

Comment: If loading from `.aws\credentials, .aws\config`, then see following link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67497387/984471

Answer (score 113):

I think you need to use for example:

```
aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster default --region us-east-1
```

This depends of your region of course.

Answer (score 103):

"You must specify a region" is a not an ECS specific error, it can happen with any AWS API/CLI/SDK command.

For the CLI, either set the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable. e.g.

`export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1`

or add it into the command (you will need this every time you use a region-specific command)

`AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1 aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster default`

or set it in the [CLI configuration file: ~/.aws/config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html)

```
[default]
region=us-east-1
```

or pass/override it with the CLI call:

`aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster default --region us-east-1`

Comment: For all available variables, see : [AWS CLI Configuration Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html)

Comment: I had a similar issue and I had `AWS_REGION` set correctly yet I was getting this error. Adding `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` solved it.

Comment: In my case I had logged in using `aws-azure-login` and subsequently when `aws <foo> <bar>` also needed to supply both region *and* profile, e.g., `--region us-east-1 --profile my-login-profile`. Just wanted to mention in case someone else runs into the same.

Comment: Why do you need a region if you were to invoke a lambda running locally via for example serverless?

Answer (score 36):

**#1- Run this to configure the region once and for all:**

```
aws configure set region us-east-1 --profile admin
```

- *Change `admin` next to the profile if it's different.*
- *Change `us-east-1` if your region is different.*

**#2- Run your command again:**

```
aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster default
```

Comment: This, not running `aws configure` or editing `.aws/config`, was the only thing that worked for me

Comment: Information pollution is very dense in this https certificate management ecosystem between servers, authority, browser and client.  It's a rube goldberg machine with actors everywhere throwing misinformational sand into the gears to throw you off.  It's taking me days of research just to find a reliable information for how these things work, let alone simple and reliable instructions for setting up HTTPS.  I guess this is what the future of computing looks like, google searches that no longer return reliable and true instructions for how to perform important actions.

Answer (score 13):

If you have configured all what is needed in `.aws/config` and `.aws/credentials` but still have this error - double-check names in square brackets.

It should be `[profile myLovelyAccName]` in `config` and `[myLovelyAccName]` in `credentials`.

Two points to note:

- the word "profile" and one space after - in the `config` file only
- no typos in the acc name!

Comment: The missing "profile" prefix in `~/.aws/config` was the reason for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Just to add to answers by Mr. Dimitrov and Jason, if you are using a specific profile and you have put your region setting there,then for all the requests you need to add

"--profile" option.

For example:

Lets say you have AWS Playground profile, and the ~/.aws/config has [profile playground] which further has something like,

`[profile playground]
 region=us-east-1`

then, use something like below

`aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster default --profile playground`

Answer (score 3):

I posted too soon however the ways to configure are given in below link

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

and way to get access keys are given in below link

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-set-up.html#cli-signup

Comment: Does it apply to only that particular ec2 instance where it is done?

Answer (score 1):

> Note: You must have [AWS CLI installed](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/?nc1=h_ls) first.

**Step 1:** Open the terminal or command prompt on your computer.

**Step 2:** Run the following command to configure the default region:

```
aws configure set default.region <your_region>
```

Replace <your_region> with the appropriate region code, for example:

> For US East (N. Virginia): **us-east-1** 
> For EU (Frankfurt): **eu-central-1**

[image]

**Step 3:** Verify the new default region by running the following command:

```
aws configure list
```

[image]

This command will display a list of your AWS CLI configurations, including the newly set default region.

By following these steps, you can configure a default region in the AWS CLI using the command line interface.