# How to see all running Amazon EC2 instances across all regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I switch instances between different regions frequently and sometimes I forget to turn off my running instance from a different region. I couldn't find any way to see all the running instances on Amazon console.
Is there any way to display all the running instances regardless of region?

Comment: Not ideal and definitely not obvious but you can use `Resource Groups > Tag Editor` as a GUI option. See my answer below.

Comment: @DanDascalescu are you sure?  How much money do you think AWS has made from people like the OP who forgot to turn off a running instance?

Comment: @DanDascalescu as smartcaveman says it's noway dumb if instances get strewn all over the many regions and forgotten about while the $ ticker tick tick ticks for the Bezos.

Comment: @DanDascalescu how would they charge people for forgetting the instances if they just showed what's running.. ?

Answer (score 210):

**Nov 2021 Edit**: AWS has recently launched the [Amazon EC2 Global View](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2globalview/home) with initial support for Instances, VPCs, Subnets, Security Groups and Volumes.

See the [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/09/amazon-ec2-global-view-console-regions/) or [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Filtering.html#global-view) for more details

---

A non-obvious GUI option is the [Tag Editor](https://console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/tag-editor/find-resources) in the Resource Groups console. Here you can find all instances across all regions, even if the instances were not tagged.
[image: Screen capture of]

Comment: @breakpoint looks like they now added back a link to the previous Tag Editor that supports multi-region search.

Comment: Appreciated, Heinrich; will review.

Comment: It would be great if aws had a built in drop down for 'all-regions' or similar

Comment: @user5783745 the screen has recently been updated and now has an "All regions" option

Comment: @HeinrichFilter So it does. I just tried it. Very handy! Thanks for pointing out

Comment: July 2021: https://eu-west-3.console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/tag-editor/find-resources

Comment: There still seems to be no AWS CLI or python SDK command available (that does not involve a loop through all the regions)

Answer (score 88):

I don't think you can currently do this in the AWS GUI. But here is a way to list all your instances across all regions with the AWS CLI:

```
for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions --region us-east-1 --output text | cut -f4`
do
     echo -e "\nListing Instances in region:'$region'..."
     aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region
done
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1777) (If you want to see full discussion)

Also, if you're getting a

> You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure"

You can do so with `aws configure set region us-east-1`, thanks @Sabuncu for the comment.

**Update**

Now (in 2019) the cut command should be applied on the 4th field: `cut -f4`

Comment: To avoid `cut`, you can use: `aws ec2 describe-regions --query Regions[*].[RegionName] --output text`

Comment: If using profiles add --profile profile-name to **both** of the aws ec2 commands.

Comment: You can use this command on Windows 10 CMD,  `FOR /F  %G IN ('aws ec2 describe-regions --query Regions[*].[RegionName] --output text') DO (aws ec2 describe-instances --region %G)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work now -- `You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".` -- seems like specifying a region is the opposite of what I want to do

Comment: @WillSheppard You must first configure your region; e.g. `aws configure set region us-east-1`.  Then, when you run `aws ec2 describe-regions`, you should have no problems.  Please see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46577479/360840 as well as other answers under the related question.

Comment: For a more succinct output, you can it inside of the for: ```aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --region $region --output text ```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 67):

**In Console**

Go to VPC dashboard [`https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home`](https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home) and click on `Running instances` -> `See all regions`.

[image]

**In CLI**

Add this for example to `.bashrc`. Reload it `source ~/.bashrc`, and run it

> Note: Except for [aws CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html) you need to have [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) installed

```
function aws.print-all-instances() {
  REGIONS=`aws ec2 describe-regions --region us-east-1 --output text --query Regions[*].[RegionName]`
  for REGION in $REGIONS
  do
    echo -e "\nInstances in '$REGION'..";
    aws ec2 describe-instances --region $REGION | \
      jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | "EC2: \(.InstanceId): \(.State.Name)"'
  done
}
```

Example output:

```
$ aws.print-all-instances 

Listing Instances in region: 'eu-north-1'..
"EC2: i-0548d1de00c39f923: terminated"
"EC2: i-0fadd093234a1c21d: running"

Listing Instances in region: 'ap-south-1'..

Listing Instances in region: 'eu-west-3'..

Listing Instances in region: 'eu-west-2'..

Listing Instances in region: 'eu-west-1'..

Listing Instances in region: 'ap-northeast-2'..

Listing Instances in region: 'ap-northeast-1'..

Listing Instances in region: 'sa-east-1'..

Listing Instances in region: 'ca-central-1'..

Listing Instances in region: 'ap-southeast-1'..

Listing Instances in region: 'ap-southeast-2'..

Listing Instances in region: 'eu-central-1'..

Listing Instances in region: 'us-east-1'..

Listing Instances in region: 'us-east-2'..

Listing Instances in region: 'us-west-1'..

Listing Instances in region: 'us-west-2'..
```

Comment: In 2021 this VPC Management Console way was the best way for me to find all regions with an EC2 Instance running. Thanks sobi3ch.

Answer (score 35):

### From `VPC` Dashboard:

1. First go to [VPC Dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home)
2. Then find Running instances and expand see all regions. Here you can find all the running instances of all region:

   [image]

### From `EC2` Global view:

- Also you can use [AWS EC2 Global View](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2globalview/home) to watch Resource summary
  and Resource counts per Region.

  [image]

Comment: This menu is changed. I couldn't find Running instances.

Comment: @RezaTaba I don't know why you couldn't find, but I can still see Running Instances. I have updated my answer, hope it may help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess the issue was me trying to access it on a phone. Found it on a pc.

Answer (score 22):

@imTachu solution works well. To do this via the AWS console...

- AWS console
- Services
- Networking & Content Delivery
- VPC
- Look for a block named "Running Instances", this will show you the current region
- Click the "See all regions" link underneath

Comment: There's no "Networking & Content Delivery" under "Services" now

Comment: in AWS console: click 'services' > in the text box type 'vpc' and then select VPC- isolated cloud resources

Comment: They have updated it again.  There is now a shortcut in the EC2 dashboard.  Go to the instances section and click on "instances".  It will show you all the running instances in the select region.

Comment: Sorry Will - it's there ! But you can go direct to VPC.
Mindfulgeek - you have missed the point: "by region" was always there in EC2, but the OP wanted to see across all regions. The VPC method allows you to see if any are there across regions

Answer (score 10):

Every time you create a resource, tag it with a name and now you can use **Resource Groups** to find all types of resources with a name tag across all regions.

Comment: This is the way to do it. No crazy loops or multiple queries. Resource groups will put that all together for you!

Answer (score 8):

After reading through all the solutions and trying bunch of stuff, the one that worked for me was-

1. List item
2. Go to Resource Group
3. Tag Editor
4. Select All Regions
5. Select EC2 Instance in resource type
6. Click Search Resources

[image: Snapshot of the solution]

Answer (score 7):

Based on imTachus answer but less verbose, plus faster. You need to have [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and [aws-cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) installed.

```
set +m
for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions --query "Regions[*].[RegionName]" --output text); do 
  aws ec2 describe-instances --region "$region" | jq ".Reservations[].Instances[] | {type: .InstanceType, state: .State.Name, tags: .Tags, zone: .Placement.AvailabilityZone}" &
done; wait; set -m
```

The script runs the `aws ec2 describe-instances` in parallel for each region (now 15!) and extracts only the relevant bits (state, tags, availability zone) from the json output. The `set +m` is needed so the background processes don't report when starting/ending.

Example output:

```
{
  "type": "t2.micro",
  "state": "stopped",
  "tags": [
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "MyEc2WebServer"
    },
  ],
  "zone": "eu-central-1b"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can run `DescribeInstances()` across all regions.

Additionally, you can:

- Automate it through Lambda and Cloud watch.
- Create api endpoint using Lambda and api gateway and use it in your code

A sample in NodeJS:

- Create and array of regions (endpoints). [can also use AWS [describeRegions()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeRegions-property)  ]

```
var regionNames = ['us-west-1', 'us-west-2', 'us-east-1', 'eu-west-1', 'eu-central-1', 'sa-east-1', 'ap-southeast-1', 'ap-southeast-2', 'ap-northeast-1', 'ap-northeast-2'];

    regionNames.forEach(function(region) {
        getInstances(region);
    });
```

- Then, in `getInstances` function, `DescribeInstances()` can be
  called.

```
function getInstances(region) {
            EC2.describeInstances(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) return console.log("Error connecting to AWS, No Such Instance Found!");
                data.Reservations.forEach(function(reservation) {
                //do any operation intended
      });
    }
```

And Off Course, feel free to use ES6 and above.

I wrote a lambda function to get you all the instances in any state [running, stopped] and from any regions, will also give details about instance type and various other parameters.

[The Script](https://jparasha.github.io/Get_All_Ec2_Instances_Across_All_Regions/) runs across all AWS regions and  calls  `DescribeInstances()`, to get the instances.

You just need to create a lambda function with run-time `nodejs`.
You can even create API out of it and use it as and when required.

Additionally, You can see AWS official Docs For [DescribeInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeInstances-property) to explore many more options.

Comment: you have to actually read the linked code for this to make sense https://github.com/jparasha/Get_All_Ec2_Instances_Across_All_Regions/blob/master/getInstances.js

Answer (score 4):

A quick [bash oneliner](https://github.com/onceupon/Bash-Oneliner) command to print all the instance IDs in all regions:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-regions --query "Regions[].{Name:RegionName}" --output text |xargs -I {} aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId] --output text --region {}

# Example output
i-012344b918d75abcd
i-0156780dad25fefgh
i-0490122cfee84ijkl
...
```

Answer (score 3):

AWS has recently launched the Amazon EC2 Global View with initial support for Instances, VPCs, Subnets, Security Groups, and Volumes.

To see all running instances go to EC2 or VPC console and click `EC2 Global View` in the top left corner.

[image]

Then click on `Global Search` tab and filter by `Resource type` and select `Instance`. Unfortunately, this will show instances in all states:

```
pending
running
stopping
stopped
shutting-down
terminated
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My script below, based on various tips from this post and elsewhere. The script is easier to follow (for me at least) than the long command lines.

The script assumes credential profile(s) are stored in file `~/.aws/credentials` looking something like:

```sh
[default]
aws_access_key_id = foobar
aws_secret_access_key = foobar

[work]
aws_access_key_id = foobar
aws_secret_access_key = foobar
```

Script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#------------------------------------#
# Script to display AWS EC2 machines #
#------------------------------------#

# NOTES:
# o Requires 'awscli' tools (for ex. on MacOS: $ brew install awscli)
# o AWS output is tabbed - we convert to spaces via 'column' command


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
# Assemble variables #
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

regions=$(aws ec2 describe-regions --output text | cut -f4 | sort)

query_mach='Reservations[].Instances[]'
query_flds='PrivateIpAddress,InstanceId,InstanceType'
query_tags='Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[]'
query_full="$query_mach.[$query_flds,$query_tags]"


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
# Output AWS information #
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

# Iterate through credentials profiles
for profile in 'default' 'work'; do

    # Print profile header
    echo -e "\n"
    echo -e "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    echo -e "Credentials profile:'$profile'..."
    echo -e "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"

    # Iterate through all regions
    for region in $regions; do

        # Print region header
        echo -e "\n"
        echo -e "Region: $region..."
        echo -e "--------------------------------------------------------------"

        # Output items for the region
        aws ec2 describe-instances    \
          --profile $profile          \
          --region  $region           \
          --query   $query_full       \
          --output  text              \
          | sed     's/None$/None\n/' \
          | sed     '$!N;s/\n/ /'     \
          | column  -t -s $'\t'

    done
done
```

Comment: If you have not done it yet, I would suggest you invalidate these credentials.

Comment: @Thiago thanks but those credentials were anyway bogus placeholders :).

Answer (score 1):

I created an open-source script that helps you to list all AWS instances. https://github.com/Appnroll/aws-ec2-instances

That's a part of the script that lists the instances for one profile recording them into an postgreSQL database with using `jq` for json parsing:

```
DATABASE="aws_instances"
TABLE_NAME="aws_ec2"
SAVED_FIELDS="state, name, type, instance_id, public_ip, launch_time, region, profile, publicdnsname"
# collects the regions to display them in the end of script
REGIONS_WITH_INSTANCES=""

for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions --output text | cut -f3`
do
   # this mappping depends on describe-instances command output
   INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES="{
        state: .State.Name,
        name: .KeyName, type: .InstanceType,
        instance_id: .InstanceId,
        public_ip: .NetworkInterfaces[0].Association.PublicIp,
        launch_time: .LaunchTime,
        \"region\": \"$region\",
        \"profile\": \"$AWS_PROFILE\",
        publicdnsname: .PublicDnsName
   }"

   echo -e "\nListing AWS EC2 Instances in region:'$region'..."
   JSON=".Reservations[] | ( .Instances[] | $INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES)"
   INSTANCE_JSON=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region)

   if echo $INSTANCE_JSON | jq empty; then
      # "Parsed JSON successfully and got something other than false/null"
      OUT="$(echo $INSTANCE_JSON | jq $JSON)"

      # check if empty
      if [[ ! -z "$OUT" ]] then
        for row in $(echo "${OUT}" | jq -c "." ); do
          psql -c "INSERT INTO $TABLE_NAME($SAVED_FIELDS) SELECT $SAVED_FIELDS from json_populate_record(NULL::$TABLE_NAME, '${row}') ON CONFLICT (instance_id)
            DO UPDATE
            SET state = EXCLUDED.state,
            name = EXCLUDED.name,
            type = EXCLUDED.type,
            launch_time = EXCLUDED.launch_time,
            public_ip = EXCLUDED.public_ip,
            profile = EXCLUDED.profile,
            region = EXCLUDED.region,
            publicdnsname = EXCLUDED.publicdnsname
            " -d $DATABASE
        done

        REGIONS_WITH_INSTANCES+="\n$region"
      else
        echo "No instances"
      fi
   else
        echo "Failed to parse JSON, or got false/null"
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

> To run jobs in parallel and use multiple profiles use this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in profile1 profile2
do
    OWNER_ID=`aws iam get-user --profile $i --output text | awk -F ':' '{print $5}'`
    tput setaf 2;echo "Profile : $i";tput sgr0
    tput setaf 2;echo "OwnerID : $OWNER_ID";tput sgr0
    for region in `aws --profile $i ec2  describe-regions --output text | cut -f4`
    do
        tput setaf 1;echo  "Listing Instances in region $region";tput sgr0
        aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value , InstanceId]' --profile $i --region $region --output text
    done &
done
wait
```

> Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how long this option's been here, but you can see a global view of everything by searching for `EC2 Global View`

https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2globalview/home#

[image: Global View Search]

Answer (score 1):

Using [bash-my-aws](https://bash-my-aws.org/):

```sh
region-each instances
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @hansaplast code I created Windows friendly version that supports multiple profiles as an argument. Just save that file as cmd or bat file. You also need to have `jq` command.

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set PROFILE=%1
IF "%1"=="" (SET PROFILE=default)

echo checkin instances in all regions for %PROFILE% account
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`aws ec2 describe-regions --query Regions[*].[RegionName] --output text --profile %PROFILE%`) DO (
echo === region: %%F
aws ec2 describe-instances --region %%F --profile %PROFILE%| jq ".Reservations[].Instances[] | {type: .InstanceType, state: .State.Name, tags: .Tags, zone: .Placement.AvailabilityZone}"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use cli tool designed for enumerating cloud resources (cross-region and cross-accounts scan) - https://github.com/scopely-devops/skew

After short configuration you may use the following code for list all instances in all US AWS regions (assuming 123456789012 is your AWS account number).

```
from skew import scan

arn = scan('arn:aws:ec2:us-*:123456789012:instance/*')
for resource in arn:
    print(resource.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good tool to [CRUD AWS resources](https://github.com/pceuropa/AWS-CRUD-Manager). Find [EC2|RDS|IAM..] in all regions. There can do operations (stop|run|terminate) on filters results.

```
python3 awsconsole.py ec2 all // return list of all instances
python3 awsconsole.py ec2 all -r eu-west-1
python3 awsconsole.py ec2 find -i i-0552e09b7a54fa2cf --[terminate|start|stop]
```