# circle ci cloudformation template aws region errror

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, circleci

I have the following circle ci template that I use from a tutorial.

```
jobs:
  create_infrastructure:
    docker:
      - image: amazon/aws-cli
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Ensure backend infrastructure exist
          command: |
            aws cloudformation deploy \
              --template-file template.yml \
              --stack-name my-stack
workflows:
  my_workflow:
    jobs:
      - create_infrastructure
```

But when I execute in in circle ci, I get

```
You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".

Exited with code exit status 253
```

Please help me troubleshoot.
[image]

Also tried adding the env vars to circleci like in the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error You must specify a region when running command aws ecs list-container-instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166957/error-you-must-specify-a-region-when-running-command-aws-ecs-list-container-inst). You need to pass the region name as an environment variable or flag as indicated in the link

Comment: It seems that these configurations don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests. You need to add region to your config:

```
jobs:
  create_infrastructure:
    docker:
      - image: amazon/aws-cli
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Ensure backend infrastructure exist
          command: |
            aws cloudformation deploy \
              --template-file template.yml \
              --stack-name my-stack \
              --region <your-region, e.g. us-east-1>
workflows:
  my_workflow:
    jobs:
      - create_infrastructure
```

**Update**

Using the command in one line, as opposed multi-line, was the solution:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file template.yml --stack-name my-stack --region eu-central-1
```

Comment: i've committed:  
```
 aws cloudformation deploy \
              --template-file template.yml \
              --stack-name my-stack
              --region eu-central-1
```
But I still get 
```
 #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
aws cloudformation deploy \
  --template-file template.yml \
  --stack-name my-stack
  --region eu-central-1


You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".

Exited with code exit status 253

CircleCI received exit code 253 
```

Comment: to add to that i did aws configure on the VM i run commits, maybe I need to set it somewhere in circleci ?

Comment: @vprocopan Try as one line, rather then breaking the command into multiple lines: `aws cloudformation deploy  --template-file template.yml  --stack-name my-stack --region eu-central-1`.

Comment: same, unfortunately

Comment: @vprocopan Are you sure that the code in question is fully representative of your actual code?

Comment: #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file template.yml --stack-name my-stack --region eu-central-1         


Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

Exited with code exit status 253

CircleCI received exit code 253

Comment: @vprocopan This is different issue. Region works.

Comment: yes it is copy paste :) I would do screenshots but stack likes text better.

Comment: understood, where do i put the credentials? environment vars in circleci? or same in command?

Comment: @vprocopan `region` error is resolved now. lack of credentials is a new issue. You can pass them using envarionmental variables in circle.

Comment: ,yes thanks! it kind of accepts the region now, but what is wrong with the credentials? as I do have them in env vars in circle, do I have to pass them directly too?

Comment: @vprocopan Have a look [here](https://techinscribed.com/deploy-frontend-application-to-aws-s3-using-circle-ci/) how you can safely pass your credentails to circle.

Comment: @vprocopan It involves circle [context](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/contexts/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229033/discussion-between-vprocopan-and-marcin).

Comment: the `--region` flag fixed it for me thanks.